# sql timestamp wrong result - now

Tags: mysql, sql

I get in trouble with MySQL 5.7 - Select on TIMESTAMP column. Here from table creation description:

```
`utc_timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

When I do

```
select * from table
```

**I see utc_timestamp result fine**

But if I do

```
select utc_timestamp from table
```

**The data shown contains not dates stored in table but current time!**

Why these two requests give me different value of utc_timestamp column data? I never saw this before, while work on MySQL, PostgreSQL, MSSQL etc. so not sure is it because I not know something or MySQL bug?

I tried from different SQL clients (MySQL Workbench 6.1 and HeidiSQL) and result is the same, so this happen on server side for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp
Utc_timestamp is a built in var, try to do
    Select table.utc_timestamp from table
Or give another, not reserved name, to the column, not to confuse you and others.

Comment: Ok, will try - just a moment

Comment: Looks like you was right about that. I put table name before column and it works now. I cannot rename table as it is full of data and actually build by other developers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

`utc_timestamp` is a reserved keyword in mysql, try adding backtick to the query

```
select `utc_timestamp` from table
```

I think it is better to change the column name and not to name columns similar to reserved language keyword so that you do not get such confusions.